# Change enum value in Database using EF

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, enums

sorry for my english, hope you're doing okay , i'm stuck in a list situation using MVC, i have a class named student

```
public class student
{

    [Key]
    public int student_Id { get; set;  }

    public DateTime startdate { get; set; }
    public DateTime enddate { get; set; }
    public statut studentstatut { get; set; }

}
public enum statut
{
  Garden,
  Elementary,
  College,
}
```

i want to edit the class student , i can edit the Id , both dates , but when i want to edit the enum statut it won't , it stays in Garden and when i check my database in studentstatut it shows 0, i don't know how to make them dynamic so that i can see the studentstatut in the database and edit the statut (for exemple edited from garden to elementary ) , can anyone help please ?

```
[HttpPost]
      [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Alimentation(Student Student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Orders.Add(Student);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(Student);
    }

 public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
       {
          if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
     }
  Student student= db.Students.Find(id);
          if (order == null)
           {
             return HttpNotFound();
        }
          return View(student);
      }

    ////POST: /Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
     public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Student_id,startdate,enddate,AtmAmount,Statut")] Student student)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
        return View(student);
    }
```

Comment: Please show us ths code where you change the value of `studentstatut`

Comment: Can you add your mapper code? how do you map the values into `studentstatut` / how do you get the values from `statut`

Comment: use static integer variables in a class, save them in the database as status. Then when you want to work with the variables use a dictionary int, string for mapping

Comment: this is what i use in the edit view     @Html.DropDownList("Statut",
                                         new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(statut))),
                                         "Statut",
                                         new { @class = "form-control" })

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. How do you save changes to database? We need more code if you wanna help

Comment: how about now ?

Answer (score 0):

First, I would verify that you are getting the correct data back from your HttpPost Edit method. If you're able to edit and save the other fields It's possible that your client-side control is not correctly setting the correct field for your student object. Put a breakpoing in that method to verify that the `studentstatut` field is correctly being set.

If it is, and it is somehow not saving to your database context, you can try manually setting the field rather than using `EntityState.Modified`. You can do that with something along the lines of:

```
db.Entry(student).studentstatut = student.stdentstatut;
```

Though usually EntityState.Modified should do the trick.